# Powershell: disable indexing of drive including folders and files

Tags: powershell, indexing

When I manually disable the drive indexing a popup appears and asks if I want to apply the change to the drive, subfolders and files whereby it takes about 30 seconds to set everything accordingly.

Now, I want to include this manual step in a PowerShell script and stumbled on this [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/Celoxocis/ac0726f823827cbbff2938b9e682fbdb):

```
function Disable-Indexing($drive) {
    $obj = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveLetter='$drive'"
    $indexing = $obj.IndexingEnabled
    if("$indexing" -eq $true){
        $obj | Set-WmiInstance -Arguments @{IndexingEnabled=$False} | Out-Null
    }
}
```

It removes the indexing of a drive but unfortunately there seems to be no option in the Win32_Volume class to apply that setting to all subfolders and files.

What should I do?

Comment: This video explains how to remove folders from being indexed **Windows PowerShell: Removing Folders From the Index** <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czR9VlSEYZ8>

Comment: This is pretty useless without the correct .dll and I am not able to open  https://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/choose/windowssearch4/developers.mspx